# Why did my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS reboot during an xorg upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, xorg

My Laptop had to upgrade some xorg upgrades recently, and this required a reboot, where during the boot process some stuff was installed. Why was that necessary? I have never experienced this with a linux operating system, only with windows. What was done during the boot process which could not be done while the system was booted?

Edit: These are the packages that were updated:

```
Start-Date: 2022-12-13  10:41:13
Commandline: packagekit role='update-packages'
Upgrade: frr:amd64 (8.1-1ubuntu1.2, 8.1-1ubuntu1.3), tzdata:amd64 (2022f-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, 2022g-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), xserver-xorg-core:amd64 (2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.3, 2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.4), xserver-xorg-legacy:amd64 (2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.3, 2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.4), xserver-common:amd64 (2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.3, 2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.4), frr-pythontools:amd64 (8.1-1ubuntu1.2, 8.1-1ubuntu1.3), xserver-xephyr:amd64 (2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.3, 2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.4)
End-Date: 2022-12-13  10:41:15
```

Comment: Snap updates sometimes install during reboot or shutdown

Comment: You could look in the apt log at /var/log/apt/history.log and figure out what packages were updated at that time. If you provide that information via an edit to your question, it should be possible to figure out why a reboot was necessary. Otherwise we're just guessing since we don't know what "some stuff" is.

Comment: I edited the question